# Reopen all the windows after shutdown

Tags: shutdown

There was once a feature that reopened all the windows on startup. Is it possible to enable that somehow, even the checkbox "Reopen all windows ..." disappeared.

Did this happen because of an update ? I it possible to revert back to an older version ?

Mac OS version 10.6.8

Comment: The reopen windows was added in 10.7; and it was never in 10.6.x

Comment: ok this makes sense now. I have an older macbook, and I had 10.7 installed on it, but I reverted the os back to 10.6 recently. I didn't knew that this feature is available only for 10.7 +

Answer (score 1):

The Feature is still there.

I do not have 10.6.8 (I have the 10.8.4) and it shows this.

[image]

If you do not see it, but had it before then check the 
Library/Saved Application State folder to see what files are in it.

I would suggest to run the <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> and run the repairs from there.